# How to call Thread.sleep within Nashorn JS Script

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I tried to use Thread.sleep() on various occassions in Nashorn but it either executes simultaneously or throws an exception. How can i use Thread.sleep() in the script

Comment: can you show the JS code in which you call the Java method?

Comment: Can you confirm that you call the fully qualified method "java.lang.Thread.sleep(ms)" in your JavaScript and not simply "Thread.sleep(ms)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to work for me with this code

```
    ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine se = sem.getEngineByExtension("js");
    int time_in_ms = 3000;
    se.put("ms", time_in_ms);
    Instant before = Instant.now();
    se.eval("java.lang.Thread.sleep(ms)");
    Instant after = Instant.now();
    System.out.printf("Expected: %dms Actual %dms%n", time_in_ms, Duration.between(before, after).toMillis());
```

I could alter `time_in_ms` and get different values, e.g.

```
Expected: 3000ms Actual 3195ms
```

(obviously they are different because of the overhead of eval-ing the javascript)

I tried under Windows with JDK1.8 and JDK11.